# Difference between Mac Address and Bluetooth Address

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mac-address

Can someone tell me the difference between Mac Address and Bluetooth Address in a BLE device?

Do they both have to be unique? 
I've read that changing the bluetooth address affects the mac address?
Is it possible to have a different bluetooth address, but the same mac address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are referring to Bluetooth Address is what more popularly known as static address which is a randomly generated address while the MAC address is unique and public.

The MAC address is created as per the IEEE 802-2001 standards in accordance with [section 9.2: "48-bit universal LAN MAC addresses"](http://www.ieee802.org/secmail/pdfocSP2xXA6d.pdf). They have a valid Organizationally Unique Identifier (OUI) obtained from the [IEEE Registration Authority](https://standards.ieee.org/products-services/regauth/index.html).

The MAC address is divided into the following two fields:

1. company_assigned field is contained in the 24 LSb.
2. company_id field is contained in the 24 MSb.

Whereas, A static address is a 48-bit randomly generated address created considering these requirements:

1. The two most significant bits of the static address shall be equal to ‘1’
2. Not all bits of the random part of the static address shall be equal to ‘1’
3. Not all bits of the random part of the static address shall be equal to ‘0’